# Why is my simple springmvc web application shutting down Jetty?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, ubuntu, jetty

Looking at my log files of a simple springmvc application (the homecontroller index action outputs 'hello world'), it seems the site is shutting down for some reason?

I simply pushed my .war file to the jetty_home/webapps folder, and started the jetty service.

```
ubuntu@ip-10-123-44-55:/usr/share/jetty/logs$ cat 2011_11_01.stderrout.log.022538550 
2011-11-01 02:15:26.080:INFO::jetty-6.1.24
2011-11-01 02:15:26.192:INFO::Deploy /etc/jetty/contexts/javadoc.xml -> org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler@8b819f{/javadoc,file:/usr/share/jetty/javadoc}
2011-11-01 02:15:26.338:INFO::Extract file:/var/lib/jetty/webapps/springmvc.war to /var/cache/jetty/data/Jetty__8080_springmvc.war__springmvc__s1aryk/webapp
2011-11-01 02:15:26.821:INFO::NO JSP Support for /springmvc, did not find org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
2011-11-01 02:15:28.245:INFO:/springmvc:Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'springmvc'
0    [main] INFO  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet  - FrameworkServlet 'springmvc': initialization started
69   [main] INFO  org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext  - Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'springmvc-servlet': startup date [Tue Nov 01 02:15:28 UTC 2011]; root of context hierarchy
145  [main] INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader  - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/servlet-context.xml]
504  [main] INFO  org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner  - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Named' annotation found and supported for component scanning
795  [main] INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor  - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
853  [main] INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1cd107f: defining beans [homeController,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0]; root of factory hierarchy
1064 [main] INFO  org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping  - Root mapping to handler 'homeController'
1446 [main] INFO  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet  - FrameworkServlet 'springmvc': initialization completed in 1445 ms
2011-11-01 02:15:29.738:INFO::NO JSP Support for , did not find org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
2011-11-01 02:15:29.746:INFO::Opened /var/log/jetty/2011_11_01.request.log
2011-11-01 02:15:29.810:INFO::Started SelectChannelConnector@:8080
hello, world!
2011-11-01 02:24:01.775:INFO::Shutdown hook executing
2011-11-01 02:24:01.775:INFO::Graceful shutdown SelectChannelConnector@:8080
2011-11-01 02:24:01.828:INFO::Graceful shutdown org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler@8b819f{/javadoc,file:/usr/share/jetty/javadoc}
2011-11-01 02:24:01.828:INFO::Graceful shutdown org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext@caf0ed{/springmvc,file:/var/lib/jetty/webapps/springmvc.war}
2011-11-01 02:24:01.828:INFO::Graceful shutdown org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext@18f6559{,file:/var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/}
2011-11-01 02:24:02.828:INFO::Stopped SelectChannelConnector@:8080
2011-11-01 02:24:02.829:INFO:/springmvc:Destroying Spring FrameworkServlet 'springmvc'
514583 [Shutdown] INFO  org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext  - Closing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'springmvc-servlet': startup date [Tue Nov 01 02:15:28 UTC 2011]; root of context hierarchy
514584 [Shutdown] INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1cd107f: defining beans [homeController,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0]; root of factory hierarchy
2011-11-01 02:24:02.834:INFO::Shutdown hook complete
```

This is a IntelliJ .war file that was built using a maven project.

This is my first deploy so please don't assume I know what I'm doing :)

**Update**

Actually it seems to be up, when I do a wget localhost:8080/springmvc/ I get the message:

```
Resolving localhost... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost|127.0.0.1|:8080... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 500 JSP support not configured
2011-11-01 02:33:34 ERROR 500: JSP support not configured.
```

For some reason this isn't working on jetty, it worked fine on tomcat?

Comment: Search the web for jetty and jsp support; this is a known configuration/library issue (answered an SO question on it a day or two ago in fact).

Answer (score 4):

if this is a maven project add the yetty plugin to your pom file

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.10</version>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

then execute the following command

```
mvn jetty:run
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [this link](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/JSP+2.0+v+JSP+2.1)

***Jetty does not implement JSP directly. Instead it uses a servlet to provide this functionality required by the servle specification. [...] the companion of 2.5 servlet specification is the 2.1 JSP specification***

So you need a jar with JSP.

If you're using Jetty 6 within the maven plugin I imagine that the dependency that Peter Szanto answered will solve it. On the other hand, if you are using it as part of your application you'll need to add an appropriate jsp jar.

For **example** for a Maven project using Jetty 6.1 you can include in the `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsp-2.1</artifactId>
  <version>6.1.14</version>
</dependency>
```